# python 2.4.3 sqlite executemany syntax

Tags: python, sqlite, executemany

I am stuck using python 2.4.3 and the sqlite module issued with that distribution.

How can i run the executemany command in this environment? The more modern syntax seems to have an issue.

```
import sqlite as sql
conn = sql.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table test(item text)''')
list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

c.executemany('''insert into test values(?)''', list)
```

Python 2.4.3 is quite old I guess and I can't find any docs, and I have no assoicated **doc** string associated with the executemany function.

I appreaciate the help.

Comment: What is the concrete error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `%s` instead of `?`:

```
import sqlite as sql
conn = sql.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table test(item text)''')
list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
c.executemany('''insert into test values(%s)''', list)
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not quite there. I get TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. I ran code exactly as above.

Comment: Got it.  In this older version it reads: .executemany('''insert into test values(%s)''', list)